# How to send an email from Apex with a template based on an Event record?

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have been trying to figure out how to send an email from Apex for a template that needs an Event object to work.

In my example below, I want to have a visualforce template that will work off of an Event record. It will have a custom controller for a component within the Visualforce Email Template which will need the Event.Id in order to query the Event and a list of child objects from another object.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'test@test.com' });
email.setTargetObjectId(myContact.Id);
email.setTemplateId(mytemplate.Id);

Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

*Questions*

- I can specify the template id as I have above, but I am not sure how to pass (if it is at all possible) the event id so that it can be used in the template.
- I am also not sure how to specify in the Visualforce Email template that this is an Event driven template.
- In addition, as there are no page parameters for the component controller to pick up the event id from, where does it get the id from?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are looking for the [setWhatId](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId) method.

As for your question about type, there is a `relatedToType` attribute for that in your opening `messaging:emailTemplate` tag ([documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm)).

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Event">
```

The Event Id comes from `setWhatId` as mentioned above.